# Is it a closed set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm in the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ where $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ and i have to prove that $I_n=[n,+\infty[, n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ is closed, is it right to take a convergent sequence $(x_k)\in I_n$ so $ x_k\geq n,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ then, $\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}x_k\geq n, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ i.e., $x\in I_n$ so $I_n$ ??
Thank you

Comment: Yes, that would show that your set in fact is closed in that metric. As a mor general conclusion, you could show that the topology induced by $d$ is the same as the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: but i dont use $d$ in the proof

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb N^*$?

Comment: @Vrouvrou, you say you didn't use $d$.  However, you did use the word "convergent"...

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^*=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$

Comment: @mathmandan is the proof change if we change $d$ ?

Comment: @Brandon - are the metrics really equivalent? $|x-y|\leqslant C|x-y|/(1+|x-y|)$ if and only if $C\geqslant 1+|x-y|$, and it's clear that no constant can satisfy that condition for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Math1000 no, the topologies are equivalent, not the metrics.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that two metrics can induce the same topology without being equivalent.

Comment: @Math1000 if i don't see the equivalence how to introduce d ?

Comment: See my corrected answer.

Comment: @Math1000 why $\frac{\left|x-x_{n_k}\right|}{1+\left|x-x_{n_k}\right|}\to 1$

Comment: That follows from $\frac t{1+t}=1-\frac1{1+t}$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1{1+t}=0$.

Comment: @Math1000 what it means |x-x_{n_k}| increases without bound for some subsequence,

Comment: There exist positive integers $n_1<n_2<\cdots$ such that $|x-x_{n_k}|<|x-x_{n_{k+1}}|$ and the sequence $\{|x-x_{n_k}|\}$ is not bounded above.

Comment: I think that we must say $\forall M>0, \exists n_{M}, |x-x_{n_M}|\geq M$ so when M go to $+\infty,$ $|x-x_{n_M}|$ do the same

Comment: @Math1000 you do the negtion of $\exists M>0,  |x-x_n|, \forall n$ it is not what you are writing at all

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying.

Comment: you say that $\exists M>0, |x-x_n|<M, \forall n$, if not, it means that you say if the assertion "$\exists M>0, |x-x_n|<M, \forall n$" is false so the negation of it is: $\forall M>0, \exists n_{M}, |x-x_{n_M}|\geq M$

Comment: @Math1000 you understand what i say ????

Answer (score 0):

Corrected answer:

Suppose $x_n\to x$ in the $d$ metric. Then there exists $M>0$ such that $|x-x_n|<M$ for all $n$. As if not, $|x-x_{n_k}|$ increases without bound for some subsequence $\{n_k\}$, which means that $\frac{\left|x-x_{n_k}\right|}{1+\left|x-x_{n_k}\right|}\to 1$, which contradicts the assumption that $d(x,x_n)\to 0$. So given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $N$ so that $n\geqslant N$ implies $d(x,x_n)<\frac\varepsilon{1+M}$. Then for $n\geqslant N$ we have
$$\frac{|x-x_n|}{1+M}< \frac{|x-x_n|}{1+|x-x_n|} = d(x,x_n) < \frac\varepsilon{1+M}, $$
so that $|x-x_n|<\varepsilon$.

Now let $x_n$ be a sequence in $I_m$ such that $|x-x_n|\to 0$ for some $x\in\mathbb R$. Since $x_n\geqslant m$ for all $n$, we must have $x\geqslant m$, so $x\in I_m$.

It follows that if $x_n$ is a sequence in $I_m$ with $d(x,x_n)\to 0$, i.e. $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the $d$ metric, then $|x-x_n|\to 0$ and hence $x\in I_m$. Therefore $I_m$ is closed with respect to the $d$ metric.

Comment: so if we change the metric, for example a metric where we can't find a relation with the usual metric, the proof change ?

Comment: My proof is actually incorrect (can you see why?), let me fix it.

Comment: I showed that $x_n$ converging to $x$ in the standard metric implies convergence of $x_n$ in the $d$ metric. But we actually need to show the converse.

Comment: I dont understand $|x-x_n|<M$